# group dictionary by values in a new nested one

Tags: python, dictionary

Goodmorning,
I need some help in ordering a Python list of dictionary.
Basically I have something like this:

```
[{'code': 'xx1', 'group': 20, 'family': 21, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
{'code': 'xx2', 'group': 20, 'family': 21, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
{'code': 'xx3', 'group': 20, 'family': 21, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
{'code': 'xx4', 'group': 9, 'family': 78, 'line': 136, 'product': 201},
{'code': 'xx5', 'group': 9, 'family': 78, 'line': 136, 'product': 201},
{'code': 'xx6', 'group': 22, 'family': 10, 'line': 245, 'product': 106},
{'code': 'xx8', 'group': 5, 'family': 17, 'line': 1, 'product': 29},
{'code': 'xx9', 'group': 5, 'family': 17, 'line': 1, 'product': 29}]
```

and I want to group by unique values of group, family, line and product and put result in something like this:

```
[{'codes': ['xx1','xx2','xx3'], 'group': 20, 'family': 21, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
{'codes': ['xx5','xx5'], 'group': 9, 'family': 78, 'line': 136, 'product': 201},
{'codes': ['xx6'], 'group': 22, 'family': 10, 'line': 245, 'product': 106},
{'codes': ['xx8','xx9'], 'group': 5, 'family': 17, 'line': 1, 'product': 29}]
```

where "codes" is a list of grouped code.

I have in mind itertools or collections.. but I can't realize.. completely stuck..
Help is very much appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, `itertools` is a very good help:

```
dd = [{'code': 'xx1', 'group': 20, 'family': 21, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
      {'code': 'xx2', 'group': 20, 'family': 21, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
      {'code': 'xx3', 'group': 20, 'family': 21, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
      {'code': 'xx4', 'group': 9, 'family': 78, 'line': 136, 'product': 201},
      {'code': 'xx5', 'group': 9, 'family': 78, 'line': 136, 'product': 201},
      {'code': 'xx6', 'group': 22, 'family': 10, 'line': 245, 'product': 106},
      {'code': 'xx8', 'group': 5, 'family': 17, 'line': 1, 'product': 29},
      {'code': 'xx9', 'group': 5, 'family': 17, 'line': 1, 'product': 29}]
```

First build a function that extracts all items except 'code':

```
func = lambda x: {k:v for k,v in x.iteritems() if k != 'code'}
```

Then with this function:

```
out = []
for d, vals in itertools.groupby(sorted(dd, key=func), key=func):
    d['code'] = [val['code'] for val in vals]
    out.append(d)
```

returns

```
[{'code': ['xx6'], 'family': 10, 'group': 22, 'line': 245, 'product': 106},
 {'code': ['xx8', 'xx9'], 'family': 17, 'group': 5, 'line': 1, 'product': 29},
 {'code': ['xx1', 'xx2', 'xx3'], 'family': 21, 'group': 20, 'line': 244, 'product': 120},
 {'code': ['xx4', 'xx5'], 'family': 78, 'group': 9, 'line': 136, 'product': 201}]
```

Comment: Perfect! Simple and elegant! Thank you